# Windows 7: Moving Program Files location during install using unattend.xml

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, setup, unattended, waik

I am planning on using an unattend.xml to create a Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit setup with *Users* and *ProgramData* on a 2nd drive.

I have found many samples of how to do this (see below).

However I would also like to move *Program Files* to a 3rd drive as well.

i.e.:

```
C:\Windows             [SSD]

D:\Users               [HDD1]
D:\ProgramData         [HDD1]

P:\Program Files       [HDD2]
P:\Program Files (x86) [HDD2]
```

I have found that this was possible using unattend.txt in XP but all documentation or examples I find about Win 7 only mention *Users* and *ProgramData*, not *Program Files*.

Is this possible using an answer file?

Sample unattend.xml for *Users* and *ProgramData*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
 <settings pass="oobeSystem">
  <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" processorArchitecture="amd64">
   <FolderLocations>
    <ProfilesDirectory>D:\Users</ProfilesDirectory>
    <ProgramData>D:\ProgramData</ProgramData>
   </FolderLocations>
  </component>
 </settings>
</unattend>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ran out of time and had to do the installation with only the *Users* and *ProgramData* settings

I'm manually changing every install to P:\

If anyone else does have an answer, please post it for future reference!